# Cordova plugin file not returning file from fileEntry

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, quasar

here is my code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cameraCallback, (fileEntry) => {
  this.teste1 = fileEntry
  fileEntry.file(function (file) {
    this.teste2 = file
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      this.teste3 = this.result
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
}, (error) => {
  this.teste4 = error
})
```

where cameraCallback is a "file:///path/to/file" image, which exists.
I want to read this image as a file, but this.teste2 is returning empty.
this.teste3 also returns empty.

Here is my filyEntry:

> File Entry { "isFile": true, "isDirectory": false, "name":
>   "1558418616412.jpg", "fullPath":
>   "/Android/data/org.cordova.quasar.app/cache/1558418616412.jpg",
>   "filesystem": "", "nativeURL":
>   "file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.cordova.quasar.app/cache/1558418616412.jpg"
>   }

How can i solve this? 
I tried many combinations of response, changing the reader function (e), is it a async problem? Didn't get any response to this, any example.

How can i read my fileEntry as a blob/file/base64 image?

Comment: Hi, did you found the answer? I have the same error, can't find solution..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`let self = this`

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cameraCallback, (fileEntry) => {

     self.teste1 = fileEntry

     fileEntry.file(function (file) {

       self.teste2 = file

       let reader = new FileReader()

       reader.onloadend = function (e) {

         self.teste3 = self.result

       }

       reader.readAsDataURL(file)

     })

    }, (error) => {

     self.teste4 = error

    })
```